# There is a file generated by an instrument with a suffix of. avs and a virtual printer as PDF

Tags: c#, pdf, avs

The software that generates the file is called avsReport, and the generated file has the suffix. avs. Assuming I use C # to convert the. avs file to PDF, this can avoid setting up a virtual printer to print as a PDF file and not affect other software

I currently have no answer. I have tried changing the printer to Microsoft printing PDF, but as a result, the default printer for my other software has been changed.

Comment: You are right. I have changed my approach and developed a printer program. Choosing this printer program allows me to output a PDF while printing, rather than trying to parse it